# Given that OpenID Connect uses JWTs for Authentication, how is the safety ensured?

Tags: jwt, openid-connect

so I am trying to understand various login (authentication) mechanisms and it seems like there are roughly 3 ways to do so viz: (please correct me if I am wrong):

- Sessions ( stateful )
- JWTs ( both stateless & stateful )
- OpenID Connect

This blog post ( [Stop using JWTs for web sessions](http://cryto.net/%7Ejoepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/) ) covers a lot of demerits of JWTs in the context of using them for maintaining sessions. When I read about OpenID Connect it turns out that they use JWT Tokens for ID Tokens to authenticate a user. The blog post describes demerits like XSS attacks, malicious javascript codes stealing tokens ( & token info) etc..

So, how does OpenID Connect ensure that it's authentication & session maintenance are secure?

Also if it is the case that JWTs are used as "short-lived one-time usage tokens", then how does one keep the user signed in without prompting them to re-login after every few minutes/hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, after a login using OpenID Connect, an access and ID-token is returned to the backend client. the ID-token is then used to create a traditional session cookie. The ID-Token is then thrown away. Once the session cookie is established,this is how the user are kept signed in. The ID-token typically have a very short lifetime. The purpose of the access token is then to access additional APIs and resources.

If you follow the modern [OAuth 2.1](https://oauth.net/2.1/) principles there should not be any security issues when you use OpenID Connect.

To keep it all secure and reduce the amount of complexity, i recommend to not to deal with tokens in JavaScript, unless you really know what you are doing.